# Check if a date range has a weekend

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

If I have 2 dates, I know I can work out how many days, hours, minutes etc are between the 2 dates using `datediff`, e.g:

```
declare @start datetime;
set @start = '2013-06-14';

declare @end datetime;
set @end = '2013-06-15';

select datediff( hour, @start, @end );
```

How do I figure out if the date range includes a weekend?

The reason why I want to know if the date range includes a weekend is because I want to subtract the weekend from the day or hour count.  i.e. if the start day is Friday, and the end date is Monday, I should only get 1 days or 24 hours.

Datepart 1 = Sunday, and datepart 7 = Saturday on my server.

Comment: What defines a "weekend?"  Do holidays ("three-day weekends") count?

Comment: In this case, a weekend simply means Saturday and/or Sunday.  I will be trying out public holidays at a later, but not important for this question. :)

Comment: First if the diff is 6 or more one of those days is a weekend. If the diff is zero, you have to check the day of week for sat or sun.  Then assume sunday is day of week 0. If day of the week for the start date is greater than day of the week for the end date, it has at least one weekend day in the range.

Comment: If the day of week (as an integer) for end date is less than that of the start date, if either day is itself a weekend, or the range is longer than one week, you have a weekend.

Comment: @LeeMeador, but if the start day is a Friday and the end day is a Monday, that's just 3 days and includes 2 weekend days...

Comment: That assumes that "day of week" starts on monday, which it doesn't do for everyone. The DayOfWeek enum of C# for instance has sunday = 0.

Comment: @oshirowanen Monday = 1. Friday = 5. 5 > 1 => weekend day included. But I think its 4 days. F, S, S, M. That's the way I looked at the problem--inclusive of both days.

Comment: The reason why I want to know if the date range includes a weekend is because I want to subtract the weekend from the day or hour count.  i.e. if the start day is Friday, and the end date is Monday, I should only get 1 days or 24 hours.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That only matters if one of the days is itself a weekend day, which is covered by my 2nd condition.

Comment: Updated question with a reason for why I want to know if the range includes a weekend.

Comment: So does start = saturday or sunday, end = monday give 0 days? How about start = friday, end = saturday or sunday giving 1 days?

Comment: @LeeMeador, datepart 1 = Sunday, and datepart 7 = Saturday on my server.

Comment: @oshirowanen Feel free to work out your own algorithm using those assumptions. I quote myself, "assume Sunday is day of week 0". The only difference is subtracting one from your numbers to let them work in my algorithm.

Comment: When the question mentions hours and minutes, it calls all these answers into question as they only deal with whole days. You realize that the answer changes if you want to consider Fri noon until Monday noon as 24 hours--12 on friday and 12 on monday and none on Sat or Sunday? I don't know what you really want but wanted to warn you about this.

Comment: I think I should start again...

Comment: Only if you need hours and/or minutes and you have to refine your question a lot. Your question is fine for days. The comments are interesting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a function that calculates working days between 2 dates, the basic query is

```
declare @start datetime;
set @start = '2013-06-14';

declare @end datetime;
set @end = '2013-06-17';
SELECT 
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @Start, @end) +1)  -- total number of days (inclusive)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @Start, @end) * 2) -- number of complete weekends in period
  -- remove partial weekend days, ie if starts on sunday or ends on saturday
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @Start) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @end) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

so you could work out if dates include weekend if working days different to datediff in days

```
  SELECT case when  (DATEDIFF(dd, @Start, @end) +1) <>
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @Start, @end) +1)  -- total number of days (inclusive)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @Start, @end) * 2) -- number of complete weekends in period
  -- remove partial weekend days, ie if starts on sunday or ends on saturday
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @Start) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @end) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) then 'Yes' else 'No' end as IncludesWeekends
```

or simpler

```
SELECT   (DATEDIFF(wk, @Start, @end) * 2) +(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @Start) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)      +(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @end) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as weekendDays
```

Comment: Looks like the sum of the last 3 terms gives him what he really wants, which is the number of weekend days included in the date range.

Comment: indeed, SELECT   (DATEDIFF(wk, @Start, @end) * 2) +(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @Start) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  +(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @end) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as weekendDays should do it - I will update answer

Answer (score 3):

You have a weekend day if any one of the following three conditions is true:

1. The day of week (as an integer) of the end date is less than the day of week of the start date
2. Either day is itself a weekend day
3. The range includes at least six days

.

```
select 
    Coalesce(
    --rule 1
    case when datepart(dw,@end) - datepart(dw,@start) < 0 then 'Weekend' else null end,
    -- rule 2
    -- depends on server rules for when the week starts
    -- I think this code uses sql server defaults
    case when datepart(dw,@end) in (1,7) or datepart(dw,@start) in (1,7) then 'Weekend' else null end,
    --rule 3
    -- six days is long enough
    case when datediff(d, @start, @end) >= 6 then 'Weekend' Else null end,
    -- default
    'Weekday')
```

Comment: @LeeMeador Rule 3 is true, Wed to Wed is 8 days

Comment: datepart 1 on my server is a Sunday, and 7 is a Saturday.

Comment: @oshirowanen then this should work... but since you updated your question to need to get a count rather than a yes or no, SQLMenace 's answer will work better.

Comment: @oshirowanen His rules still work if you use 1-7 for the days of the week. Really, any consecutive run of 7 integers. For example, 100 to 106 for Sun to Sat would work. As long as Sunday is the low number it works.

Answer (score 1):

One way, just showing you how you can use a table of numbers for this

```
declare @start datetime;
set @start = '2013-06-14';

declare @end datetime;
set @end = '2013-06-15'; -- play around by making this 2013-06-14 and other dates


IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM(
SELECT DATEADD(dd,number,@start) AS SomeDAte 
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(dd,number,@start) BETWEEN @start AND @end) x
WHERE DATEPART(dw,SomeDate) IN(1,7))  -- US assumed here
SELECT 'Yes'
ELSE
SELECT 'No'
```

Example to return all weekends between two dates

```
declare @start datetime;
set @start = '2013-06-14';

declare @end datetime;
set @end = '2013-06-30';



SELECT DATEADD(dd,number,@start) AS SomeDAte 
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(dd,number,@start) BETWEEN @start AND @end
AND DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(dd,number,@start)) IN(1,7)
```

Results

```
2013-06-15 00:00:00.000
2013-06-16 00:00:00.000
2013-06-22 00:00:00.000
2013-06-23 00:00:00.000
2013-06-29 00:00:00.000
2013-06-30 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following functions. The first moves a given start- or enddate to monday(friday if backwards) if it begins in the weekend. The second calculates the seconds between two dates without weekends. Then you just need to check if the total-days equals the days without weksends(demo below).

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[__CorrectDate](
    @date DATETIME,
    @forward INT
)

RETURNS DATETIME AS BEGIN
    IF (DATEPART(dw, @date) > 5) BEGIN

        IF (@forward = 1) BEGIN
            SET @date = @date + (8 - DATEPART(dw, @date))
            SET @date = DateAdd(Hour, (8 - DatePart(Hour, @date)), @date)
        END ELSE BEGIN
            SET @date = @date - (DATEPART(dw, @date)- 5)
            SET @date = DateAdd(Hour, (18 - DatePart(Hour, @date)), @date)
        END
        SET @date = DateAdd(Minute, -DatePart(Minute, @date), @date)
        SET @date = DateAdd(Second, -DatePart(Second, @date), @date)
    END

    RETURN @date
END

GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[__DateDiff_NoWeekends](
    @date1 DATETIME,
    @date2 DATETIME
)

RETURNS INT AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @retValue INT

    SET @date1 = dbo.__CorrectDate(@date1, 1)
    SET @date2 = dbo.__CorrectDate(@date2, 0)

    IF (@date1 >= @date2)
        SET @retValue = 0
    ELSE BEGIN
        DECLARE @days INT, @weekday INT
        SET @days = DATEDIFF(d, @date1, @date2)
        SET @weekday = DATEPART(dw, @date1) - 1

        SET @retValue = DATEDIFF(s, @date1, @date2) - 2 * 24 * 3600 * ((@days + @weekday) / 7) 
    END

    RETURN @retValue
END
```

Then you can get the info in this way:

```
declare @start datetime
set @start = '20130614'

declare @end datetime
set @end = '20130615'

declare @daysTotal int
declare @daysWoWeekends int

SET @daysTotal = DATEDIFF(dd, @start, @end)
SET @daysWoWeekends = dbo.__DateDiff_NoWeekends(@start, @end) / (24 * 3600)

SELECT CASE WHEN @daysTotal = @daysWoWeekends
       THEN 'No weekend between'
       ELSE 'There are weeksends' END,
       @daysTotal,
       @daysWoWeekends,@start,@end
```

Here's a **demo**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7cda7/11

```
There are weeksends 1   0   June, 14 2013 00:00:00+0000 June, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple and generalize query . you can achieve result through  recursive query . Check following query

```
with mycte as
(
  select cast('2013-06-14' as datetime) DateValue
  union all
  select DateValue + 1 from mycte where DateValue + 1 < '2013-06-17'
)

select count(*) as days , count(*)*24 as hours
from    mycte
WHERE DATENAME(weekday ,DateValue) != 'SATURDAY' AND 
DATENAME(weekday ,DateValue) != 'SUNDAY'
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

it will definitely work for you .

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to get the dates between the range

```
     WITH    CTE_DatesTable
          AS ( SELECT   @MinDate AS [EffectiveDate]
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   DATEADD(dd, 1, [EffectiveDate])
               FROM     CTE_DatesTable
               WHERE    DATEADD(dd, 1, [EffectiveDate]) <= @MaxDate )

            SELECT  [EffectiveDate]
            FROM    CTE_DatesTable
    OPTION  ( MAXRECURSION 0 );
```

and then Filter out the Weekends using ..

```
((DATEPART(dw, DT.EffectiveDate) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem, although in my case I wanted a onehot encoded binary list of columns (Mon-Sun) of whether two dates contain that DOW using Impala SQL.

```
select ...

max(case when tripduration > 6 then 1
         when 2 >= dayofweek(tripstartdate) and 2 <= dayofweek(tripstartdate) + tripduration then 1
         when 2 <= dayofweek(tripenddate)   and 2 >= dayofweek(tripenddate) - tripduration   then 1 else 0 end) as '2 mon',

max(case when tripduration > 6 then 1
         when 3 >= dayofweek(tripstartdate) and 3 <= dayofweek(tripstartdate) + tripduration then 1
         when 3 <= dayofweek(tripenddate)   and 3 >= dayofweek(tripenddate) - tripduration   then 1 else 0 end) as '3 tue',

max(case when tripduration > 6 then 1
         when 4 >= dayofweek(tripstartdate) and 4 <= dayofweek(tripstartdate) + tripduration then 1
         when 4 <= dayofweek(tripenddate)   and 4 >= dayofweek(tripenddate) - tripduration   then 1 else 0 end) as '4 wed',

max(case when tripduration > 6 then 1
         when 5 >= dayofweek(tripstartdate) and 5 <= dayofweek(tripstartdate) + tripduration then 1
         when 5 <= dayofweek(tripenddate)   and 5 >= dayofweek(tripenddate) - tripduration   then 1 else 0 end) as '5 thu',

max(case when tripduration > 6 then 1
         when 6 >= dayofweek(tripstartdate) and 6 <= dayofweek(tripstartdate) + tripduration then 1
         when 6 <= dayofweek(tripenddate)   and 6 >= dayofweek(tripenddate) - tripduration   then 1 else 0 end) as '6 fri',

max(case when tripduration > 6 then 1
         when 7 >= dayofweek(tripstartdate) and 7 <= dayofweek(tripstartdate) + tripduration then 1
         when 7 <= dayofweek(tripenddate)   and 7 >= dayofweek(tripenddate) - tripduration   then 1 else 0 end) as '7 sat',

max(case when tripduration > 6 then 1
         when 1 >= dayofweek(tripstartdate) and 1 <= dayofweek(tripstartdate) + tripduration then 1
         when 1 <= dayofweek(tripenddate)   and 1 >= dayofweek(tripenddate) - tripduration   then 1 else 0 end) as '1 sun'

from ....
```